Please help me to understand the Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]

ERROR: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\petProject\dinamic-website\app\database\db.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\petProject\dinamic-website\app\database\db.php(16): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\petProject\dinamic-website\app\database\db.php(27): selectAll() #2 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\petProject\dinamic-website\app\database\db.php on line 16

file connect.php
$driver = 'mysql'; $host = 'localhost'; $db_name = 'dinamic-site'; $db_user = 'root'; $db_pass = 'mysql'; $charset = 'utf8'; $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

try { $pdo = new PDO( "$driver:host=$host; db_name=$db_name; charset=$charset", $db_user, $db_pass, $options ); } catch (PDOException $i) { die("Database connection error"); }

file db.php
function selectAll($table) { global $pdo; $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table"; $query = $pdo->prepare($sql); $query->execute(); $errInfo = $query->errorInfo();

if ($errInfo[0] !== PDO::ERR_NONE) { echo $errInfo[2]; exit(); } return $query->fetchAll();


Typo: where it says db_name it should say dbname.
